# Being asked to multiply but continue to receive " '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'", regardless of conversion

Tags: python, pandas, regression, statsmodels

I'm attempting to create a third regression model for a project and being instructed to do the following:

Regression Models
There have to be 3 regression models.

Part III h) is not included.

Part III h) is the model from Part III g) plus two interactive variables
Where the Interactive Variables are created by multiplying the country dummies with the ab_page variable, for example:
`df_merged['US_inter'] = df_merged['country_UK']*df_merged['ab_page']`
You do the same for both of the country variables include in Part III g), and add both interactive variables to the 3rd regression model, Part III h).

**Here is my code**:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

# Convert columns to the correct data types
df_merged['country_CA'] = df_merged['country_CA'].astype(int)
df_merged['country_UK'] = df_merged['country_UK'].astype(int)
df_merged['country_US'] = df_merged['country_US'].astype(int)
df_merged['ab_page'] = df_merged['ab_page'].astype(int)


# Create the interaction variables
df_merged['US_inter'] = df_merged['country_US'] * df_merged['ab_page']
df_merged['UK_inter'] = df_merged['country_UK'] * df_merged['ab_page']

# Define the dependent variable (conversion) and independent variables
y = df_merged['converted']
X = df_merged[['intercept', 'ab_page', 'country_US', 'country_UK', 'US_inter', 'UK_inter']]

# Instantiate the logistic regression model
logit_model = sm.Logit(y, X)

# Fit the model
logistic_regression_result = logit_model.fit()

# Display the summary of the logistic regression model
print(logistic_regression_result.summary())
```

**Here is the error**:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-6251061c8b0e> in <module>()
     10 
     11 # Create the interaction variables
---> 12 df_merged['US_inter'] = df_merged['country_US'] * df_merged['ab_page']
     13 df_merged['UK_inter'] = df_merged['country_UK'] * df_merged['ab_page']
     14 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in f(self, other, axis, level, fill_value)
   1552             return _combine_series_frame(self, other, na_op,
   1553                                          fill_value=fill_value, axis=axis,
-> 1554                                          level=level, try_cast=True)
   1555         else:
   1556             if fill_value is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py in _combine_series_frame(self, other, func, fill_value, axis, level, try_cast)
   1437         # default axis is columns
   1438         return self._combine_match_columns(other, func, level=level,
-> 1439                                            try_cast=try_cast)
   1440 
   1441 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _combine_match_columns(self, other, func, level, try_cast)
   4767     def _combine_match_columns(self, other, func, level=None, try_cast=True):
   4768         left, right = self.align(other, join='outer', axis=1, level=level,
-> 4769                                  copy=False)
   4770 
   4771         new_data = left._data.eval(func=func, other=right,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in align(self, other, join, axis, level, copy, fill_value, method, limit, fill_axis, broadcast_axis)
   3548                                             method=method, limit=limit,
   3549                                             fill_axis=fill_axis,
-> 3550                                             broadcast_axis=broadcast_axis)
   3551 
   3552     @Appender(_shared_docs['reindex'] % _shared_doc_kwargs)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in align(self, other, join, axis, level, copy, fill_value, method, limit, fill_axis, broadcast_axis)
   7368                                       copy=copy, fill_value=fill_value,
   7369                                       method=method, limit=limit,
-> 7370                                       fill_axis=fill_axis)
   7371         else:  # pragma: no cover
   7372             raise TypeError('unsupported type: %s' % type(other))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _align_series(self, other, join, axis, level, copy, fill_value, method, limit, fill_axis)
   7462                     join_index, lidx, ridx = self.columns.join(
   7463                         other.index, how=join, level=level,
-> 7464                         return_indexers=True)
   7465 
   7466                 if lidx is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in join(self, other, how, level, return_indexers, sort)
   3770             this = self.astype('O')
   3771             other = other.astype('O')
-> 3772             return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)
   3773 
   3774         _validate_join_method(how)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in join(self, other, how, level, return_indexers, sort)
   3780             if self.is_monotonic and other.is_monotonic:
   3781                 return self._join_monotonic(other, how=how,
-> 3782                                             return_indexers=return_indexers)
   3783             else:
   3784                 return self._join_non_unique(other, how=how,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _join_monotonic(self, other, how, return_indexers)
   4046                 join_index, lidx, ridx = self._inner_indexer(sv, ov)
   4047             elif how == 'outer':
-> 4048                 join_index, lidx, ridx = self._outer_indexer(sv, ov)
   4049             join_index = self._wrap_joined_index(join_index, other)
   4050 

pandas/_libs/join_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.join.outer_join_indexer_object()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

```
Here is a readout of the data columns:
user_id                  int64
timestamp       datetime64[ns]
group                   object
landing_page            object
converted                int64
intercept                int64
ab_page                  int64
country                 object
country_CA               int64
country_UK               int64
country_US               int64
country_CA               int64
country_UK               int64
country_US               int64
country_CA               int64
country_UK               int64
country_US               int64
country_CA               int64
country_UK               int64
country_US               int64
country_CA               int64
country_UK               int64
country_US               int64
country_CA               int64
country_UK               int64
country_US               int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: One of your columns that you are trying to multiple is probably a string and not an integer

Comment: post a sample of your data so we can help better

Comment: I'll add it above but my conversion in the code should work, no?

Comment: It seems that some of the conversions failed. Maybe becuase you have '<' in one of the columns

Comment: I just checked the two .csv files and neither have a '<'

Comment: I'm at a loss lol

Comment: It looks to me the problem is in the index and not in the values.

Comment: @JoshVanDyke It is likely that sorting was attempted in a situation where str and int are mixed. It is likely that there is something in your data or index that mixes str and int, and even if you did not sort it directly, there is something in the function you used that sorts. And if you want to get an answer, don't just say what you want to say, follow other people's requests.

Comment: PLEASE post the first 5 rows of your dataframe

Comment: post the output from: df.head()